Can the theorem of polynomial finite differences be proven without induction?
The fundamental theorem of finite differences states that for any polynomial of degree n,
$$\Delta^n p(x) = \text{constant}: ~\forall x \in R $$
Where $\Delta p(x)$ denotes the  first order difference given by $p(x+h)-p(x)$ and $\Delta^2 p(x) = \Delta\Delta p(x)$ and so on.
The usual proofs of this use induction on a polynomial of degree $k$. Can this be proven without induction?

Given a polynomial $P$ define $(\Delta P)(x)=P(x+1)-P(x)$. Given a polynomial $P$ where $P(x)= a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n$, we claim that
$$
\Delta^{n}(P)(x)=n!a_{n}\tag{0}\label0.
$$
To see this write
$$
 P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k=  \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k \sum_{m=0}^{k}S(k,m)x^{\underline{m}}\tag{1}\label1
$$
where $S(k,m)$ is the stirling number of the second kind. and $x^{\underline{m}}$ is the falling factorial. Since $\Delta(x^{\underline m})=mx^{\underline{m-1}}$, $\Delta^{n}(x^{\underline {m}})=m^{\underline n}x^{\underline{m-n}}$. If $m<n$, then $\Delta^{n}(x^{\underline {m}})=0$. Hence taking $\Delta ^{n}$ of both sides of (1) yields that
$$
(\Delta^nP)(x)=n!S(n,n)a_{n}=n!a_{n}\tag{2}\label2.
$$
